# java.time.ZonedDateTime not import in android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8

i am try to use Java 8 feature in my app , so i make some configuration according to google  [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html) to use java 8 feature but still not work [check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrV6F.png)

my build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ameerhamza6733.dwnews"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Android does not support all Java 8 language features

Comment: You might consider using Jake Wharton's [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), which is an Android-friendly wrapper around [ThreeTenBP](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp), which has a backport of `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 2):

`ZonedDateTime` is not one of the [supported Java 8 features](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html#supported-features). You'll note there is [no java.time package in the Android reference documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html).

Comment: ok then do you have any idea how to convert How to Convert RFC-1123 date-time formatter, to local time

i am gatting time Thu, 25 Aug 2016 08:59:00 GMT in this formate in my android app , i need to convert to local time , do you have any idea how i can do this ?

Comment: @AmeerHamza - that sounds like a totally separate question you should ask if you can't find [an answer that works for you](https://www.google.com/search?q=Convert%20RFC-1123%20android)

Comment: i think this is not a separete beause it is java8 Date and time formatter check this link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: The `java.time` package does not exist on Android. You won't be able to use any of those APIs.